# string constants causing unexpected type collisions in xtext

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar, xtext

I've boiled down the problem to a very simple grammar.

```
Model:
    (greetings+=Greeting* | greetings+=FrGreeting*);

Greeting:
    'Hello' person=ID '!';

FrGreeting:
    'Bonjour' person=('jacques' | 'philippe') '!';
```

In a file you can greet people in english or in french but not both.  We only know the names of 2 french people.

The problem is you cannot greet jacques in English.

```
Hello jacques!
```

results in `mismatched input 'jacques' expecting RULE_ID`.  I am very confused at why this would be.  How would I fix it?

**edit:**
Doing something like this:

```
Greeting:
    'Hello' person= AllNames '!';

FrGreeting:
    'Bonjour' person=(FrenchNames) '!';

AllNames: ID | FrenchNames ;

FrenchNames: 'jacques' | 'philippe';
```

Fixes the compile error issue. However it prevents auto-complete from working, and `jacques` and `philippe` are still highlighted like keywords (even when written as `Hello jacques!`).

**edit 2:**
This seems to fix the auto complete bug:

```
Greeting:
    'Hello' person= AllNames '!';

FrGreeting:
    'Bonjour' person=('jacques' | 'philippe') '!';

AllNames: 'jacques' | 'philippe' | ID;
```

**My questions:**
Why would a a string constant in 1 branch change the way the ID terminal is ingested along a different code path?  Is it implemented with terminals (This would seem to contradict the documentation)?  Is it a bug?

Is my edited solution the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: that is all my code. minus the standard imports.  It's an xtext grammar by the way.

Comment: (Wild guess) `enperson=ID` or `person=(ID)` (because of exclamation)?

Comment: nope. that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

That grammar doesn't make much sense to me, but I guess (if I understood you correctly) you can do what you want with the following:

```
Model:
  (greetings+=Greeting* | greetings+=FrGreeting*);

Greeting:
  'Hello' person=PersonName '!';

FrGreeting:
  'Bonjour' person=PersonName '!';

PersonName : ID | 'jacques' | 'philippe';
```

Comment: I want the "hello" case to accept anything, and the "Bonjour" case to only accept the two names.  From my understanding of the parser one of these branches shouldn't interfere with another.

Comment: I edited my question, and I think I have almost figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right way to the problem. And, you are near with the reason.
The reason is that the constant string in the grammar is a TOKEN. The ID is also a TOKEN. They are all lexer term. But 'constant string' TOKEN is considered as 'key word'. And it has higher priority than other TOKEN. So when you input 'jacques' in the editor, the parser see a token 'jacques' instead of token ID. But, the rule 'Greeting' expects a token ID.

Comment: Do you think my purposed solution is the best fix?  Is there a way to make some things not keywords but still ingested as such through the data rules?